# Excel: find location of Max value across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have a workbook containing 8 worksheets which are all of the same format. I have built a formula to calculate the Max value in a particular cell across all the worksheets:

```
=MAX(MAX('Equipment - A:Equipment - H'!C17))
```

This works great. It finds me the Max value out of the 8 instances of cell C17.

What I now want to know is which sheet that Max value is found on. I tried to use the `MATCH` function, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
=MATCH(MAX('Equipment - A:Equipment - H'!C17),'Equipment - A:Equipment - H'!C17)
```

returns `#N/A`.

All my Google searches tend to point to using `VLOOKUP` but this seems like a bit of a sledgehammer tactic.

Any ideas?

Comment: afaik, you're going to have to nest 8 statements (vlookup, match, etc) to return a string that looks like a worksheet name or use vba.

Comment: It might be easier to set up a table of 8 columns with a formula like `='Equipment - A'!C17` continued out for each worksheet, then you can set conditional formatting for the max in that range and see the max and which sheet it came from visually.

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

I'll psuedo code this since there are too many unknown details, but essentially, as you said each of the sheets is the same format, so you can use Excel Power Query (builtin 2016, add-in to 2010/2013),  to open and reformat **ONE** of the sheets to:
 1) **INCLUDE** the name of the sheet, and;
 2) exclude all of the other rows you don't don't need (eg only the max row).

This can be applied as a function call in PQ ([see this link](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/19/combine-multiple-worksheets-using-power-query/)) to open AND process all of the other tabs. At the end of each process, the resulting output can be merged to a seperate work table, and when completed will require a vlookup() to that temp/helper sheet/table to return the needed value (remember, I said PQ can incoprorate the sheet name as one of the data attributes from the 'imported' sheet.)